# Setup eclipse to test android apps on mac OS

Tags: android, macos, selenium, appium

I have used eclipse on windows machine to test android apps.
Now I have to setup eclipse on Mac OS. Is that possible ?
If yes, Can any one please help in detail on how to setup eclipse on MAC OS so that I can use it to test android apps ?

Comment: Is it a must for you to use Eclipse? Android Studio works great with Mac and not to mention with Eclipse you'll have to integrate ADT manually. https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html

Comment: I'm preferring eclipse because I have good hands on eclipse and I have never used android studio.
So, Only ADT integration is enough to work on mac ??

Answer (score 0):

You can download eclipse from [Here](https://eclipse.org/downloads/). And then you have to download android SDK and add it to your eclipse. 
I recommend using Android studio instead. As studio is now specifically android IDE. [Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Any special changes to be done related to mac that is different from windows ??

Comment: I don`t have a Mac, so I am not sure, But it should be more or less like windows.